# How can I get a class from a jQuery datatable row object?

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have a jQuery datatable row:

```
 table = $('#reports').DataTable()
 row = table.row(rowIndex)
```

How do I get the HTML class from it? (It is striped, and I want to find out if it is odd or even.)

I have tried:

```
row.hasClass('odd')

row.className

row.attr('class')
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use **[`node`](http://datatables.net/reference/api/row%28%29.node%28%29)** with `className`:

```
row.node().className;
```

Comment: Thanks :)  DataTables documentation does leave something to be desired.

Comment: The solution used in the fiddle for my now deleted answer here -> http://jsfiddle.net/d9r5n0hp/

Comment: @davidkonrad, your answer may actually be better.  Try mine with row 4.  I get nothing, while you get "odd."

Comment: Have undeleted my answer, but still thinks yours are better. Have not tested in depth. http://jsfiddle.net/d9r5n0hp/1/

Comment: Hmm. You are right. It is in fact a very, very good question. Have to go to bed, but will tomorrow look into what the he** I have done myself, for this particular situation. I know I have been here before.

Answer (score 3):

It is a really a good question. The ordinary jQuery way, by using `row.index()`:

```
var rowClass = $("#example tbody tr:eq(" + row.index() + ")").attr('class');
```

Proof of concept -> **http://jsfiddle.net/7jy46wz4/**

Answer (score 0):

Taking what @rick-hitchcock said, another approach is to use the following code in validations:

```
var hasOddClass = $(row.node).hasClass("odd");
```

which, by the examples you gave, should be closer to what you want.